# PHP: unable to save data in database

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having a bit of trouble on this. I'm not sure if this information is important but this script was working at one point, but it kept making multiple records for every submission (It seemed like it was making a  submission for every inputted form value)

eg. if first name and last name were entered, 2 records would be created.

Besides that though, this is the code I'm having trouble with right now:

**(connection.php)**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "contacts";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if($conn)
{
echo "Connection OK!";
}
else
{
    die("Connection failed");
}   
?>
```

**(index.html)**

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$fn = isset ($_GET['first_name'])? $_GET['first_name'] : null;
$ln = isset ($_GET['last_name'])? $_GET['last_name'] : null;

$query = "INSERT INTO contact VALUES ('fn','ln')";
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($data)
{
echo "Data inserted!";
}
?>
```

the connection seems to be working just fine because i'm getting a "Connection OK" message, and the variables also seem to change based on the form values... but the query will not work no matter what I do now (I'm trying to fill a table with the above values if that isn't obvious)... I'm using Apollo 2.435 in case there is a plugin issue and you know how I could fix that (That also seems to be working seeing as all of the above code is working within an HTML document)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you intend to insert the same values all the time `VALUES ('fn','ln')` or should it be `VALUES ('$fn','$ln')`.  You should be using prepared statements as well.  I would also recommend listing the column names your inserting into as well.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is *not* your database. MySQL is. phpMyAdmin is just a tool to make managing your database easier. That's a very basic fundamental distinction that you should know *before* you start working with databases.

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: I understand PHPmyadmin isnt my database, but I dont see how thats relevant with this problem seeing as phpmyadmin isnt shown in any of my code.

Comment: or how you came to that conclusion*

Comment: geuss @JohnConde came up with that conclusion because you tagged the question with phpmyadmin also..

Comment: Also, @NigelRen thanks for your response, ill keep that in mind. My main problem is that the query wont execute though. ;(

Comment: @RaymondNijland I tagged PHPmyadmin incase it was a plugin issue

Comment: I used the mysqli_error(mysqli_query) -- Not sure if I did that right. But this is the error I got -- Warning: Use of undefined constant mysqli_query - assumed 'mysqli_query' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\crm\index.html on line 53

Comment: you need to use `mysqli_error($conn)`;

Comment: @RaymondNijland nothing is coming back for 'mysqli_error($conn)' ;/

Comment: `$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: i commented almost the same comment as @dmikester1 so i removed that one `mysqli_error()` is a "fetch" function not a "echo" function.  So you need to use it in combination with `die()` like dmikeste or with print and echo functions;  something like `if($data == false) { echo mysqli_error($conn); }`

Comment: @dmikester1 & Raymond I changed it to what you said (I'm new to this so you kind of have to be specific and i apologize) but this is the error I'm getting now:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.'','')' at line 1

Comment: Try `$query = "INSERT INTO contact VALUES ('".$fn."','".$ln."')";` The single quotes around the variable names maybe your issue.

Comment: Or try the answer that was posted 4 hours ago. Not sure why it was downvoted as it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try prepared statements to insert records:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contact (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $fn, $ln);
$fn = $_GET['first_name'];
$ln = $_GET['last_name'];
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi guys, I accidently did 'fn' and it should have been '$fn' (it was just a typo on my end and it still doesnt work.) More help would be greatly appreciated.